# Log4net : Append new event logs to same log file regardless of date and time

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

In my application, a new log file will be generated everytime my application starts. However, this is not what I want because sometimes, I would end up with 10 log files due to opening and closing my application 10 times at different times.

I want my log file to be named `Log_LOGFILECREATEDDATE_LOGFILECREATEDTIME.txt`. All subsequent events performed in that application is to be logged to just that log file no matter how many times I start the application. A new log file should be created only if the old log file is renamed or deleted.

**Code in App.config**

```
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\Log_%date{yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date{dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} %level - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

**How I log things in my application**

```
public class ABC{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog logMe = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    ....
    function A(int a)
    {
          ...
          logMe.Info("function A done!")
     }
}
```

Comment: I'd probably look at storing the log file name in an app setting or similar, and the application starts it looks for that log file and continues to use it if it exists. If it doesn't, it creates a new log file and updates the setting.

Answer (score 0):

Change your configuration `<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\Log_%date{yyyyMMdd_HHmmss}.txt" />` to `log4net.Util.PatternString" value="D:\Log_myapplicationname.txt" />`

But in production you will end up with a large file, so consider RollingFileAppender - https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to ask log4net to scan the directory for all files that match your "pattern" and choose the latest one, which is essentially what you're asking it to do. How about the compromise of using a static file name and logging a startup time message each time your application starts up?